# Issue with expand on video jquery

Tags: jquery

I have some issue with my code and firefox.

I have a video which expand when I have my mouse over if, it works well on chrome but on firefox the expand won't stop:

```
$('#media-video').hover(
  function(){
    $('#video').stop().animate({
      left: "-=188",
      width: '+=188px',
      height: '+=81px',
    }, 300);
    player.play();

  }, function(){

    $('#video').stop().animate({
      left:0,
      width: '306px',
      height: '192px'
    }, 300);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w10pzdyu/

Comment: You don't have `player.stop()` there. Please complete the full function.

Comment: It 's not about the player but about the expand when I have my mouse over the video , just ignore video.play()

Comment: Ah okay. Can you see if there are any console errors in Firefox?

Comment: i have no error in the console